# Terminus drush config:import detecting no changes

Tags: import, drupal, drush, pantheon

I cloned a multi-dev environment to my local machine and the website is working fine. I have the database, files, and code working on the local machine. The problem I'm encountering is when I make changes to a content type like adding a new field in the blog post or changing the sitename, it's not changing my production site in Pantheon.

Here are the commands I'm running:

In my local machine:

1. drush cex - this works
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "change message"
4. git push to my branch not master
5. terminus drush myPantheonsitename.multi-devname -- config:import

After running step 5 command in terminal, it's telling me that there are no changes to import. I feel as though export and import are looking at different location. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: As if pull not being triggered on Pantheon and updated config never reached there OR config already imported (maybe automatically by Pantheon).  What's "my branch" connected to? How does code usually get deployed to Prod exactly? Did you merge "my branch" already? Can it be that the config already has been imported automatically?

Comment: I solved the problem that I've been working on for 2 days. The solution is below: I basically had to write a new command in settings.php. The command i typed is $settings['config_sync_directory'] = 'sites/default/sync';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by going to settings.php and adding this line of code:

$settings['config_sync_directory'] = 'sites/default/sync';

For some reason, the above code wasn't included in the multi-dev environment I cloned.